# MySQL table update using jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a main php file and a javascript file. I want to update each field in my form by using jQuery/AJAX. I have all the right database update sql, etc. It's my jQuery that is wrong. I have a table tahts called profiles. Here are the column names:

[image: Profiles]

As of now, when I click the update button, it redirects me to a blank page, with the updated information displayed in the page url. When I check my database, nothing has been saved.

*This is a wordpress plugin*

*Here is my code*

**jQuery update**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    eventHandlers = function () {
        $('#cm-list').delegate('.update', 'click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var row         = $(this).parent()[0],
                htmid       = row.id,
                id          = htmid.replace('no_', ''),
                fname       = $('.fname', row).val(),
                lname       = $('.lname', row).val(),
                sex         = $('.sex', row).val(),
                nationality = $('.nation', row).val(),
                position    = $('.position', row).val(),
                json        = { 'id': id, 'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'sex': sex, 'nationality': nation, 'position': position };
            if (fname.length > 1) {
                $.post(ajaxurl, { action: 'updateprofile', 'pro_data': json }, function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $.jGrowl(custom.profile_name + fname + lname + custom.edited, { header: custom.yes });
                    }
            });
        } 
                    else {
                        $.jGrowl(custom.err, { header: custom.no });
                    }
        });
    },
    cm_init = function () {
        eventHandlers();
    };

cm_init();
```

});

**Php code just to show you my sql**

*My function updateprofile() is inside __construct()*

*add_action(wp_ajax...... ajax hooks*

```
function update() {
            if (!isset($_POST['pro_data'])) {
                return;
            }
            $this->db_update($_POST['pro_data']);
        }
function db_update($input) {
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . CM_PROTBL,
                                array('fname'       => $input->fname,
                                      'lname'       => $input->lname,
                                      'sex'         => $input->sex,
                                      'nationality' => $input->nationality,
                                      'position'    => $input->position
                                    ),
                                array('id'          => $input->id),
                                array('%s',
                                      '%s',
                                      '%s',
                                      '%s',
                                      '$s'
                                    ),
                                array('%d')
                            );

        if ($this->return_result($result)) {
            $this->renderprofile($input);
        }
    }

function renderprofile($input) {
            $output = array(
                'fname'         => $input->fname,
                'lname'         => $input->lname,
                'sex'           => $input->sex,
                'nationality'   => $input->nationality,
                'position'      => $input->position
            );
            $this->renjson($output);
        }
```

Unable to find answers for this so any help is appreciated!

**Edit:** At the moment, no errors with the jQuery. When I click the update button. It brings me to a blank page, with the url containing the information I submitted, which is useless to me. I want it to update instantly and alert the user, etc.

**Edit:** Getting uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token if now, If I take out the semi-colon. If I leave it in after the json variable, it gives me unexpected token error, how to solve this?
[image: Error]

**Edit:** I have now fixed this error, it was my mistake, I had an extra bracket. It's not going to a white blank page now. The text is coming up, e.g. Profile John has been modified. But still nothing has changed in the database.

Comment: should not this: $('.fname', row).val() ==> $('.fname'+ row).val() ?

Comment: Why the + after fname?

Comment: do you see any errors in the console ? try $('.fname, ' + row) instead. I thought you mistakenly added comma instead + but you are using multiple selectors instead. The comma should be in quotes I believe.

Comment: Ok, I now see an error on this line json        = { 'id': id, 'fname': fname, 'lname': lname, 'sex': sex, 'nationality': nation, 'position': position }; Uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token ; I took out the ; and now its giving me an error with my if statement? I'll try the quotes now too, thanks!

Comment: @ZafarAhmad I have used your method and still no joy.

Comment: The error states you have an invalid JSON formatted string, you need to check if thats a  case

Comment: I'm not getting that error anymore

Comment: can you do a console.log with the json string and also, check the AJAX method if its sending the params to the PHP side or not

Comment: Ok, i'm getting this Parse error on line 1:
json={    'id': id,
^
Expecting '{', '[' and i do not no how to check the ajax method, can you help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74786/discussion-between-zafar-ahmad-and-crsmc).